# Python countdown function for telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I found a countdown function on
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/countdown-timer
which i want to imply to my telegram bot function.
When the below code run, it will send the message to the bot immediately and after 5s.
But what i want is to send the message only after 5s.
Could someone tell me what's wrong with the code? Greatly appreciate.

```
import time
import telegram_bot
def countdown(time_sec):
    while time_sec:
        mins, secs = divmod(time_sec, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        time_sec -= 1
    telegram_bot.telegram_bot_sendtext("Intruder detected!!")
countdown(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just this:

```
import time
import telegram_bot
def countdown(time_sec):
    time.sleep(time_sec)
    telegram_bot.telegram_bot_sendtext("Intruder detected!!")
countdown(5)
```

but if you want to use this function this would prevent initial message:

```
import time
import telegram_bot
def countdown(time_sec):
    while time_sec:
        mins, secs = divmod(time_sec, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        time_sec -= 1
    if time_sec == 0:
        telegram_bot.telegram_bot_sendtext("Intruder detected!!")
countdown(5)
```

Comment: Openvino, [2/1/2022 8:35 PM]
Intruder detected!!

Openvino, [2/1/2022 8:35 PM]
Intruder detected!!

After i run with if function, it appears the same result as before

Comment: I found out the first message would send with import telegram_bot without call this function. But how to call this function without import it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a more elegant and simple solution:

```
import time


def countdown(message, timex):
    elapsed_time = 0
    while elapsed_time < timex:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        time.sleep(1)  # checks every second
        elapsed_time = elapsed_time + time.perf_counter() - start

    telegram_bot.telegram_bot_sendtext("Intruder detected!!")


countdown("Intruder detected!!", 5)
```

If you wanted to run this function in the background while the rest of the code keeps running, you can do this:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures


def countdown(telegram_message, timex):
    elapsed_time = 0
    while elapsed_time < timex:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        time.sleep(1)  # checks every second
        elapsed_time = elapsed_time + time.perf_counter() - start

    telegram_bot.telegram_bot_sendtext(telegram_message)


msg= "Intruder detected!!"
delay = 5

concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().submit(lambda: countdown(msg, delay)).result()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i should think it easier, which is combined two functions.
And it worked

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
import requests


def countdown(telegram_message, timex):
    elapsed_time = 0
    while elapsed_time < timex:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        time.sleep(1)  # checks every second
        elapsed_time = elapsed_time + time.perf_counter() - start
    def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):   
        bot_token = 'XXX
        bot_chatID = 'XXX
        send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
        response = requests.get(send_text)
        return response.json()
    test = telegram_bot_sendtext("Intruder detected!!")

msg= "Intruder detected!!"
delay = 5

concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().submit(lambda: countdown(msg, delay)).result()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).